# C# Rectangle.Contains Win10 error

Tags: c#, winforms

While going over the code for a simple Pong like game I had a pupil of mine write, we ran into a bug that I can't reproduce or figure out.

The offending code is as follows:

```
if (this.ball.X <= this.p1.paddle.Right)
{
    this.newball = !this.p1.paddle.Contains(this.ball.Location); // bug here????
    if (!this.newball) { lasthit = this.p1; }
}
```

Note: the ball doesn't have a variable speed (+/- 10 px each frame), and each paddle is 20 pixels in width, both paddle and ball are `Rectangle` types.

This is simple enough: if the ball is less than the right edge of the paddle, check to see if the ball is contained in the paddle. If the paddle contains the ball then the ball was "hit" by the paddle and thus a new ball doesn't need to spawn.

**The problem:** even if the ball was directly in the middle of the paddle, the `newball` flag is set (confirmed by stepping through the debugger and validating the X,Y values of each to confirm the `ball` is indeed contained within the `paddle`).

**The caveat:** this code works exactly as expected on my Windows 7 machine and my other Windows VM's that I could test this on, while the code produces the bug every time on my pupil's Windows 10 machine.

I copied the project/solution from his machine and ran it directly on mine (both running VS2012 .NET 4), side by side with the paddles in identical positions (center screen) so the ball should "bounce", and on mine it "bounced" as expected while on his a "new ball" was spawned. More interesting is the player 2 paddle responded as expected on both machines.

We restarted his Visual Studio instance as well as ran the executable directly (in both debug and release) on his machine and it caused the bug each time.

I've never seen an issue like this (especially with C#) and we're not using any advanced language features as it's just a teaching exercise to understand semantics, scope, etc. etc., so I'm not sure why `!this.p1.paddle.Contains(this.ball.Location)` would work any differently on any machine?

Has anyone seen any issues like this before? Are there any other environmental settings that I might be able to check on his machine to see why this would cause an error?

I can post the rest of my pupil's code if requested (only about 200 lines), but the rest of the code is not at issue.

Comment: Not sure what bug I'm supposed to be looking for in this code.  Seems to work on my Windows 10.  Instead of Contains, you can test if the ball is between the top and the bottom, in cases where the speed of the ball is actually going past the rectangle.

Comment: You've posted way too much code. See [mcve] to understand what sort of _complete_ code example is required. I can tell you that the Windows 7/10 aspect is practically certain to be a red herring; you may find slight differences in exact behaviors across installations or even OSs, but the bug is in your code somewhere. It just happens in some cases to not be visible/triggered. I also guarantee that the `Rectangle.Contains()` method works the same on all OS versions, and will always do the right thing.

Comment: If you think it's not doing the right thing, it's because you've either misunderstood the inputs you're giving it, or the result you're getting out of it. Please narrow the code example down to some specific and repeatable sequence of program statements that reliably reproduces the issue you're having.

Comment: Finally, keep in mind the comment above from @Lars. I disagree with his proposed fix, but the potential issue certainly needs to be addressed. Specifically, assuming the "ball" has variable speed and can potentially move more than the thickness of the "paddle" in a single frame of animation, you will have situations where the ball should be blocked by the paddle but the two never touch. The right way to address it is to check whether the ball's path (the line segment between the current position and the next) intersects either the top or bottom edge of the paddle (also line segments).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'll disagree on the too much code comment.  The OP posted a working example that is easily copied and working in your own environment.  200 lines of code is not too bad for a project like this.

Comment: @LarsTech: any code that is more than is _strictly required_ fails to meet the "Minimal" part of the standard. I agree the code here is better than is often provided by the average SO petitioner. But the fact is, none of us can use this code example to reproduce whatever problem the person is having (so not "Verifiable"), and whatever problem the person is having certainly _must_ be reproducible without relying on the timing of the machine or the person using the program (so not "Minimal").

Comment: Just tested on Win10, VS15: Right Paddle works, Left is 'go-through'.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I do understand the inputs quite well, I've also removed the unnecessary code. My question isn't why I don't understand my _pupil's_ code, my question is why that line fails only on his machine only (i.e. I can't reproduce the bug to prove/disprove any assertions). If it's a matter of some minor difference (maybe his screen resolution was slightly different), that could explain, but I didn't check that in the time I had with his machine/code.

Comment: I don't understand your question about why you can't reproduce it. What are the values when the error occurs? Once you have them, you can reproduce the error to your heart's content.

Comment: @iheanyi, that's exactly my point. When run on my _pupil's_ Windows 10 machine, the bug occurs, but when run in the same environment on my Windows 7 machine (side by side), the code runs as expected. It's possible screen resolution might need to be taken into account? But there wasn't anything that shouted "this is the bug" in his code as to why it would work differently. I did have the values when the error occurred, and I couldn't reproduce on _my_ machine which segues to my other question .. was there something I misunderstood or an environmental issue (like resolution) that I missed.

Comment: Presumably you've checked what version of .net you're both using?

Also, check you're both using the same DPI settings... different OS UI scaling on the system is a possible culprit.

Comment: @MeirionHughes, I did check the .NET versions, etc. and I checked the resolution (his could have been just slightly different and I misread, i.e. 1366 vs 1360) .. but I didn't think to check DPI (which I will next time I meet up). But would DPI have any effect on something like that (versus just the resolution itself)?

Comment: No, that is *not* your point. Because you've yet to post the values which on your pupil's machine cause the *wrong* behavior but on your machine work fine. So I, and everyone here, has no reason to believe the conditions are identical. Since you've isolated code where you think the problem is happening, the simple thing to test is give us the values of the parameters in question where your pupil sees and error and you don't. You claim the parameters are Rectangles so I can't see how you'd be disclosing sensitive information or why it would be hard to capture given it happens under debug.

Comment: @iheanyi, which I can do when I see him next. In the mean time, I was inquiring if there was some other factor that I may have missed as to why I could not reproduce this bug on my machine given the same values. I did post the entire code previously, but since removed it (as it was not apparently relevant). I'm not trying to argue that I'm right in any way to anyone on here, simply trying to help a student with a bug in his code :)

Comment: That should have been the first thing you did, check for what values you're getting newBall when you didn't expect it. At this point, there is not enough information to explain why you are seeing different results absent some bug in the OS or .NET runtime. If you are running identical code - the only difference **must** be the input to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong (line 142):

```
   if (dx < 0) {
                if (this.ball.X <= this.p1.paddle.Right)
```

Change to

```
   if (dx < 0) {
                if (this.ball.X < this.p1.paddle.Right)
```

And the left paddle works as expected, too.

Note that

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 100);
Point p1 = new Point(10, 30);
Point p2 = new Point(30, 30);
bool test1 = r.Contains(p1);   // true
bool test2 = r.Contains(p2);   // false
```

`test2`is `false` because the rectangle goes from x=10 to x=29!

I can't test on an earlier OS atm, but I somehow doubt this ever was different.. But maybe the ball moves differently??

Comment: I wont see this pupil for a few days but I'll change his code and run it on his machine to see if that fixes this issue (makes sense given). There are some other things I can look at on his machine to see what the differences were (maybe screen res was slightly different and that would account), then I can inform him that the `<` is appropriate and why. His code works as expected on my Win7 machine with `<=` or `<` so I can't verify :/